# Bootstrap Custom Column arrangement

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css

Im using twitter bootstrap and i want my cols arrangement to be flexible such that no vertical spacing is there in between div, somewhat like this 
[image: No vertical space is left empty]

but instead what i have is

```
 jsfiddle.net/37ogy4qh
```

how can i archive this?

Additionaly im using:

- Angular JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the gapless grid, the solution isn't Bootstrap by itself. You'll need an additional plugin such as [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) which will create the correct effect. They play along with Bootstrap just fine.